# Angularjs - show values from a server request

Tags: json, angularjs, output

I got this json data back from the server: {"start":"29-11-2014","end":"31-12-2014","pris":"372.27"}

In my .success i have $scope.paymentInfo = data; then i try to output it in my html view like this

{{ paymentInfo.start }}

but it does not work but if i try {{ paymentInfo }} it shows the json object, what do i have to do, to get the start, end etc. ?

```
        $scope.selectMembership = function(values){

        //console.log(values);


        centerSettings.getPriceForPeriod(values)

            .success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.paymentInfo = data;
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('fejl ved hentning af centre');
                console.log(data);
            });
    };
```

Comment: When you do {{paymentInfo}} is it showing the *object*, or the json string? What format is the data coming back from the server, and what mime-type? Are you sure it isn't being treated as a string as opposed to interpreted?

Comment: my output is this: http://cl.ly/image/091a1x0i0e2U this output is text/html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to deserialize the string to Json object.

Try using `$scope.paymentInfo = angular.fromJson(data);`

Comment: and on safari it says Error: JSON Parse error: Unable to parse JSON string

Comment: Doh, it was because my model was returning json_encode and my controller did it too. it all works now Thanks so much! :)